# how to use filter parameters and Grep command together for listing all GITHUB pull request from a repository

Tags: github, grep

I am looking for an option to get all pull requests with ID, Name, Date, and count of files committed from GitHub.

I managed to get all pull requests using API, but listing only the required parameter is not working. Can anyone help?

***curl -X GET -u :https://api.github.com/repos/XXXX/XXXX/pulls?state=all&page=1&per_page=100| egrep -w 'title|number|state|created_at|updated_at'***

Grep is working if the query is like below, without multiple filter parameters (*state=all&page=1&per_page=100*)

***curl -X GET -u :https://api.github.com/repos/XXXX/XXXX/pulls?state=all| egrep -w 'title|number|state|created_at|updated_at'***

Can anyone help how to list only the required data with multipe filter parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try grep with something like this:
grep -Pa 'state'